# Helping optimize filter results code in JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm quite new to developing in PHP, using MySQL with addition of JS. I would like an expert opinion on the following, or any good advise will do.

So I am making a website that is probably simple for most of you but a bit complex for me, which allows logged users to create events and attend to ones.

Recently I added a new feature - frontend filtering events by category as I would like to get some practice on JS as well. Haven't tried backend filtering yet tho.

The thing is it is working fine but the JS code itself in my opinion looks really poor and messed up.

Therefore I was thinking of a way to optimize it but could not find any.

.html code of category selection

```
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="filterCat"onchange="filterCategory()">
 <option selected>All</option>
 <option value="1">Concerts</option>
 <option value="2">Sport</option>
 <option value="3">Comedy</option>
 <option value="4">Theatre</option>
 <option value="5">Family attractions</option>
</select>
```

php query to determine size of loop

```
<?php
// ...
require_once('../features/con.php');
if (!$con->connect_errno) {
 $countQ = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM events;";
 $resultCounting = $con->query($countQ);
 $size = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCounting);
}
// ...
?>
```

filtering results algorithm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var catinput, cat, evinput, events, table, i, t, txtValue, number, num, tableRes, none, no, tableID, tr, td;
  number = <?php echo $size['number'] ?>;

  function filterCategory() {
    catinput = document.getElementById('filterCat');
    cat = catinput.options[catinput.selectedIndex].text;
    t = "table";

    for (var j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
      num = j;
      tableRes = t.concat(num);
      none = document.getElementById(tableRes).style.display;
      if (none == "none") {
        document.getElementById(tableRes).style.display = "";
      }
    }
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      no = i;
      tableID = t.concat(no);
      table = document.getElementById(tableID);
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      td = tr[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      txtValue = td.innerText;
      if (cat != "All") {
        if (cat.toUpperCase() != txtValue.toUpperCase()) {
          document.getElementById(tableID).style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById(tableID).style.display = "";
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Each separate table with different event has unique ID, which is determined based on a event_id table column in database (this is auto incremented column from 1, that sets automatically).

I made an associative array to list all the events from database and simply add this one:
`id="table<?php echo "$row[event_id]"?>"`

But this JS code itself - can it be optimized somehow? Perhaps you have any ideas?

Any tips really appreciated!

Comment: So if im understanding correctly, you have a table for each event and if you change the selectbox you want to only show the tables (events) from that category?

Comment: @Reyno precisely! Except "All" select box that show all the tables, despite their categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright their are alot of changes i suggest. Not only for performance but also for readability.

First of all i gave every table a data property which we will later use for filtering. I also changed the values of the selectbox to match these of the dataset.

Inside the JS i select the items only ones. You use the `getElementBy` inside every itiration of the loop meaning the JS needs to look at the DOM many times and instead of using multiple loops i wrote it all in a single one. Since it can be done in a single one.

At last i used ES6 syntax since it allows me to use things like [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [for of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [destructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
// Get the selectbox
const selectBox = document.querySelector("#filterCat");
// Get all the tables
const events = document.querySelectorAll(".event");

// Add eventlistener to trigger whenever the value changes
selectBox.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // Get selected value
  const { value } = selectBox;
  
  // Loop over each event (table)
  for(const event of events) {
    // Show the table
    event.style.display = "table";
    
    // Continue to the next one if we want to show all tables
    if(value === "All") continue;
    
    // Get type from dataset
    const { type } = event.dataset;
    // If it is not the selected category hide it
    if(value !== type) {
      event.style.display = "none"
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="filterCat">
 <option selected>All</option>
 <option value="concert">Concerts</option>
 <option value="sport">Sport</option>
 <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
 <option value="theatre">Theatre</option>
 <option value="family-attractions">Family attractions</option>
</select>

<table class="event" data-type="concert">
  <tr><td>Concert 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="sport">
  <tr><td>Sport 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="comedy">
  <tr><td>Comedy 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="theatre">
  <tr><td>Theatre 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="family-attractions">
  <tr><td>Family attractions 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="concert">
  <tr><td>Concert 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="sport">
  <tr><td>Sport 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="comedy">
  <tr><td>Comedy 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="theatre">
  <tr><td>Theatre 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="family-attractions">
  <tr><td>Family attractions 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Version without comments:

```js
const selectBox = document.querySelector("#filterCat");
const events = document.querySelectorAll(".event");

selectBox.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const { value } = selectBox;
  
  for(const event of events) {
    event.style.display = "table";
    
    if(value === "All") continue;
    
    const { type } = event.dataset;
    if(value !== type) {
      event.style.display = "none"
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="filterCat">
 <option selected>All</option>
 <option value="concert">Concerts</option>
 <option value="sport">Sport</option>
 <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
 <option value="theatre">Theatre</option>
 <option value="family-attractions">Family attractions</option>
</select>

<table class="event" data-type="concert">
  <tr><td>Concert 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="sport">
  <tr><td>Sport 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="comedy">
  <tr><td>Comedy 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="theatre">
  <tr><td>Theatre 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="family-attractions">
  <tr><td>Family attractions 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="concert">
  <tr><td>Concert 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="sport">
  <tr><td>Sport 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="comedy">
  <tr><td>Comedy 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="theatre">
  <tr><td>Theatre 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="event" data-type="family-attractions">
  <tr><td>Family attractions 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, although I was thinking about making another filter that has 3 another options: to show all events, ones organized by user or the one he is attending to. I was thinking whether I should use frontend text (at the bottom of each table there's a button that says either 'resign', 'going' and 'delete', which value is based upon database query - whether user is taking part in a event, organizing event or has no connection to it at all). Do you think I should make another query to db or just use what the button itself says?

Answer (score 1):

```
var catinput, cat, evinput, events, table, i, t, txtValue, number, num, tableRes, none, no, tableID, tr, td;
  number = <?php echo $size['number'] ?>;
```

You declare every vars at the beginning of your script but some are just locally used in functions or loops.
The variables that are only used in a function should be declared in the loops.
In your script,
`num`, `tableRes`, ... must be declared at the beginning of the loop  `for (var j = 1; j <= number; j++) {}`

Also, you declare a empty variables to populate them right after. Give their value directly.

Your script will end like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function filterCategory() {
    var evinput, events, i, txtValue, number;
        number = <?php echo $size['number'] ?>,
        catinput = document.getElementById('filterCat'),
        cat = catinput.options[catinput.selectedIndex].text;
        t = "table";

    for (var j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
      var num = j,
          tableRes = t.concat(num),
          none = document.getElementById(tableRes).style.display;

      if (none == "none") {
        document.getElementById(tableRes).style.display = "";
      }
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      if (cat != "All") {
        var no = i,
            tableID = t.concat(no),
            table = document.getElementById(tableID),
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
            td = tr[1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0],
            txtValue = td.innerText;
            
        if (cat.toUpperCase() != txtValue.toUpperCase()) {
          document.getElementById(tableID).style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById(tableID).style.display = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: There are other optimizations. You repeat `document.getElementById(tableID)` several times but it is already in the variable `table` in your last loop

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler implementation. I am using `DIV`s in place of tables to keep the code brief.

```js
function filter_tables() {
  var selected = document.getElementById('table-selector').value;
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll('.table');
  if(selected === 'all') {
    tables.forEach( t => { t.className = 'table'; });
  } else {
    tables.forEach( t => {
      if(t.id === 'table'.concat(selected)) {
        t.className = 'table';
      } else {
        t.className = 'table hidden';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div.table {
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 12px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
div.table.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="table-selector" onchange="filter_tables();">
  <option value="all" selected>All</option>
  <option value="1">Table 1</option>
  <option value="2">Table 2</option>
  <option value="3">Table 3</option>
</select>
<div class="table" id="table1">Table 1</div>
<div class="table" id="table2">Table 2</div>
<div class="table" id="table3">Table 3</div>
```